# Mathematical fonts in Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, fonts

I am reading the following (mathematical) website https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/
in android (using chrome webreader).  The problem is that mathematical formulas and even simple symbols like integration sign do not show.  What can I do to repair this situation?